# What are the adjoint functor pairs corresponding to common monads in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, category-theory

In category theory, a monad can be constructed from two adjoint functors. In particular, if *C* and *D* are categories and  *F : C --> D* and *G : D --> C* are adjoint functors, in the sense that there is a bijection

> *hom(FX,Y) = hom(X,GY)*

for each *X* in *C* and *Y* in *D* then the composition *G o F : C --> C* is a monad.

---

One such pair of adjoint functors can be given by fixing a type `b` and taking `F` and `G` to be

```
data F b a = F (a,b)
data G b a = G (b -> a)

instance Functor (F b) where
  fmap f (F (a,b)) = F (f a, b)

instance Functor (G b) where
  fmap f (G g) = G (f . g)
```

and the bijection between hom-sets is given (modulo constructors) by currying:

```
iso1 :: (F b a -> c) -> a -> G b c
iso1 f = \a -> G $ \b -> f (F (a,b))

iso2 :: (a -> G b c) -> F b a -> c
iso2 g = \(F (a,b)) -> let (G g') = g a in g' b
```

in which case the corresponding monad is

```
data M b a = M { unM :: b -> (a,b) }

instance Monad (M b) where
    return a    = M (\b -> (a,b))
    (M f) >>= g = M (\r -> let (a,r') = f r in unM (g r') a)
```

I don't know what the name for this monad should be, except that it seems to be something like a reader monad that carries around a piece of over-writeable information (**edit:** dbaupp points out in the comments that this is the `State` monad.)

So the `State` monad can be "decomposed" as the pair of adjoint functors `F` and `G`, and we could write

```
State = G . F
```

So far, so good.

---

I'm now trying to figure out how to decompose other common monads into pairs of adjoint functors - for example `Maybe`, `[]`, `Reader`, `Writer`, `Cont` - but I can't figure out what the pairs of adjoint functors that we can "decompose" them into are.

The only simple case seems to be the `Identity` monad, which can be decomposed into any pair of functors `F` and `G` such that `F` is inverse to `G` (in particularly, you could just take `F = Identity` and `G = Identity`).

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: The monad you construct is the state monad.

Comment: Ah, of course. I'll add this to my list of "times I have reinvented a well-known monad instance without realising it."

Comment: The decomposition of a monad into a composition of appoint functors is not unique, in fact, for any monad there is a whole category of such decompositions. Probably the two most useful decompositions are terminal and initial ones: the ones in which the right adjoint is the forgetful functor from (1) the category of algebras for the monad (the Eilenberg-Moore category) and (2) the category of free algebras for the monad (the Kleisli category).

Comment: @Omar: What is this category called?

Comment: @Sebastien: I don't think it has a fully standardized name, but if you call it "the category of adjunctions for the monad" everyone will know what you mean.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Kleisli category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleisli_category). It was originally developed to show that every monad can be constructed from two adjoint functors.

The problem is that Haskell `Functor` is not a generic functor, it's an endo-functor in the Haskell category. So we need something different (AFAIK) to represent functors between other categories:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies, KindSignatures #-}
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Category hiding ((.))
import qualified Control.Category as C
import Control.Monad

class (Category c, Category d) => CFunctor f c d | f -> c d where
    cfmap :: c a b -> d (f a) (f b)
```

Notice that if we take `->` for both `c` and `d` we get an endo-functor of the Haskell category, which is just the type of `fmap`:

```
cfmap :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

Now we have explicit type class that represents functors between two given categories `c` and `d` and we can express the two adjoint functors for a given monad. The left one maps an object `a` to just `a` and maps a morphism `f` to `(return .) f`:

```
-- m is phantom, hence the explicit kind is required
newtype LeftAdj (m :: * -> *) a = LeftAdj { unLeftAdj :: a }
instance Monad m => CFunctor (LeftAdj m) (->) (Kleisli m) where
    cfmap f = Kleisli $ liftM LeftAdj . return . f . unLeftAdj
    -- we could also express it as liftM LeftAdj . (return .) f . unLeftAdj
```

The right one maps an object `a` to object `m a` and maps a morphism `g` to `join . liftM g`, or equivalently to `(=<<) g`:

```
newtype RightAdj m a = RightAdj { unRightAdj :: m a }
instance Monad m => CFunctor (RightAdj m) (Kleisli m) (->) where
    cfmap (Kleisli g) = RightAdj . join . liftM g . unRightAdj
    -- this can be shortened as RightAdj . (=<<) g . unRightAdj
```

(If anybody know a better way how to express this in Haskell, please let me know.)

Answer (score 18):

- `Maybe` comes from the free functor into the category of pointed sets and the forgetful functor back
- `[]` comes from the free functor into the category of monoids and the forgetful functor back

But neither of these categories are subcategories of Hask.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I've managed to work through the details of these two - now to figure out what the corresponding functors are for the other examples.

Comment: And `Cont r` comes from the adjunction of the contravariant functor *Op r : Hask^op --> Hask* with itself, with *Op r a = a -> r*.

Comment: Pretty sure these are both Eilenberg-Moore adjunctions, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 9):

As you observe, every pair of adjoint functors gives rise to a monad. The converse holds too: every monad arises in that way. In fact, it does so in two canonical ways. One is the Kleisli construction Petr describes; the other is the Eilenberg-Moore construction. Indeed, Kleisli is the initial such way and E-M the terminal one, in a suitable category of pairs of adjoint functors. They were discovered independently in 1965. If you want the details, I highly recommend the [Catsters videos](http://www.youtube.com/user/TheCatsters).

Comment: Thanks Jeremy - several people have recommended the Catsters to me, I really should check them out.

Comment: What is F -| G of the Eilenberg-Moore adjunction for the state monad ?