# Composition of two functors is a functor

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory

In [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13939606/546084), Petr Pudlak defined the `CFunctor` class, for functors other than those from *Hask* to *Hask*. Re-writing it a bit using type families, it looks like

```
class CFunctor f where
  type Dom f :: * -> * -> *               -- domain category
  type Cod f :: * -> * -> *               -- codomain category
  cmap :: Dom f a b -> Cod f (f a) (f b)  -- map morphisms across categories
```

with instances that look like, e.g.

```
instance CFunctor Maybe where
  type Dom Maybe = (->)                   -- domain is Hask
  type Cod Maybe = (->)                   -- codomain is also Hask 
  cmap f = \m -> case m of
                   Nothing -> Nothing
                   Just x  -> Just (f x)
```

In category theory, whenever *F : C --> D* is a functor and *G : D --> E* is a functor, then the composition *GF : C --> E* is also a functor.

I'd like to express this in Haskell. Since I can't write `instance CFunctor (f  . g)` I introduce a wrapper class:

```
newtype Wrap g f a = Wrap { unWrap :: g (f a) }
```

In writing the `CFunctor` instance I get as far as

```
instance (CFunctor f, CFunctor g, Cod f ~ Dom g) => CFunctor (Wrap g f) where
  type Dom (Wrap g f) = Dom f
  type Cod (Wrap g f) = Cod g
  cmap = undefined
```

but I can't figure out what the implementation of `cmap` should be. Any advice?

**PS** the eventual reason for all this is to also introduce a class `Adjunction` with methods `unit` and `counit`, and then automatically derive monad instances from adjunctions. But first, I need to show the compiler that the composition of two functors is also a functor.

I'm aware that I could use `cmap.cmap` on an object of type `g (f a)` and that would work, but it seems a little like cheating - surely a functor is just a functor, and the compiler shouldn't have to know that it's actually the composition of two other functors?

Comment: For endofunctors on Hask, the `DeriveFunctor` extension would certainly handle that (and many other cases) automatically. But if you have to manually implement it, I don't see why you'd expect anything simpler than mapping over composed functors by composing maps over each?

Comment: Basically, `cmap f = cmap (cmap f)` is the definition of the composition of functors, so why should using that be cheating in any way?

Comment: @C.A.McCann I'd be happy to write `cmap = cmap . cmap` as the implementation, but that's not correct for the type constructor `Wrap g f` (in particular, it takes `Dom f a b` to `Cod g (g (f a)) (g (f b))` rather than `Cod g (Wrap g f a) (Wrap g f b)`. As stated, I'm particularly interested in cases *other* than endofunctors on Hask.

Comment: @DanielFischer Because `g (f a)` isn't just the composition of two functors, it's also a functor itself, so I think I should be able to use `cmap` on it (kind of similar to how you don't have to write `lift . lift . lift` all over the place when using monad transformers, if you can tell the compiler how to lift certain functions automatically -- here I want to tell the compiler how to map a morphism across two categories with a single application of `cmap`).

Comment: I meant using that in the definition of `cmap` for `Wrap f g`. But, looking at it, I don't see how to do it for general `g`; only for `Cod g = (->)` is it obvious.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, that's the exact problem I'm having! I can write it for functors to *Hask* but not for more general functors.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this requires a way of lifting `Wrap` and `unWrap` into `g`'s target category. Given standard `Control.Category`, you can write: `arr unWrap >>> cmap (cmap f) >>> arr Wrap`.

Comment: You could use `unsafeCoerce` instead of `arr`, because `Wrap` and `unWrap` are no-ops...

Comment: @Vitus that works perfectly (with an `Arrow (Cod g)` constraint - will need to think more about that). Do you want to convert that comment to an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given functors `F : C → D` and `G : D → E`, a functor composition `G ∘ F : C → E` is a mapping of objects between categories `C` and `E`, such that `(G ∘ F)(X) = G(F(X))` and a mapping between morphisms such that `(G ∘ F)(f) = G(F(f))`.

This suggests that your `CFunctor` instance should be defined as follows:

```
instance (CFunctor f, CFunctor g, Cod f ~ Dom g) => CFunctor (Wrap g f) where
  type Dom (Wrap g f) = Dom f
  type Cod (Wrap g f) = Cod g
  cmap f = cmap (cmap f)
```

However, composing `cmap` twice gives you `Dom f a b -> Cod g (g (f a)) (g (f b))` and `cmap` in this instances has a type `Dom f a b -> Cod g (Wrap g f a) (Wrap g f b)`.

We can get from `g (f a)` to `Wrap g f` and vice versa, but since the instance declaration doesn't make any assumptions about the structure of `Cod g`, we are out of luck.

Since we know that functor is a mapping between categories, we can use the fact that `Cod g` is a `Category` (on Haskell side, this requires a `Category (Cod g)` constraint), this gives us few operations to work with:

```
cmap f = lift? unWrap >>> cmap (cmap f) >>> lift? Wrap
```

This, however, requires a convenient lifting operator `lift?`, which lifts a function from `Hask` category to `Cod g` category. Writing `Cod g` as `(~>)`, the type of `lift?` must be:

```
lift? :: (a -> b) -> (a ~> b)

lift? unWrap  :: Wrap g f a ~> g (f a)
cmap (cmap f) :: g (f a)    ~> g (f b)
lift? Wrap    :: g (f b)    ~> Wrap g f b

lift? unWrap >>> cmap (cmap f) >>> lift? Wrap :: Wrap g f a ~> Wrap g f b
```

Now, there are at least two choices for this lifting operator:

- You could expand the constrait from `Category (Cod g)` to `Arrow (Cod g)` in which case the lifting operator becomes `arr`,
- or, as Sjoerd Visscher mentions in comments, you could use the fact that `Wrap` and `unWrap` are semantically `id` at runtime, in which case the use of `unsafeCoerce` is justified.

Comment: I suspect that in the presence of type families, `unsafeCoerce` might be a bad choice. Haven't worked out any details, admittedly.